# Header на каждой странице при помощи vue.js

Tags: html, vue.js

Только начал изучать vue.js и решил при помощи него сделать хедер на сайте так, чтобы он размещался в одном файле Header.vue, а на каждую страницу просто добавить скрипт и всё. Header.vue выглядит так:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/header.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/change_button_color.css">

<template>
    <header>
        <a href="/" ><input type="button" class="buttons " value="Main page"/></a>
        <a href="/login" ><input type="button" class="buttons " value="Login"/></a>
        <a href="/registration" ><input type="button" class="buttons " value="Registration"/></a>
        <a href="/admin/admin-page" ><input type="button" class="buttons " value="Admin Page"/></a>
        <a href="/logout-page" ><input type="button" class="buttons " value="User info"/></a>

    </header>
</template>

<script>
    export default{

    }
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Вот так я добавляю хедер на обычную страницу :

```
...
<script src="js/Header.vue"></script>

    <script>
        import Header from 'static/js/Header'
        export default {
            components:{
                'my-header':Header
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<my-header></my-header>
...
```

Я вроде бы всё делаю по туториалу, но на веб-странице ничего не отображается. Скорее всего запутался в мелочах.
p.s. ещё два маленьких вопроса: нужно ли мне добавлять   `<script src="js/Header.vue"></script>` или следующего импорта достаточно? и второй: нужно ли добавлять ссылки на css внутри Header.vue или же мне нужно стили прописать напрямую в  в Header.vue, а css файлы со стилями не нужны? Если что, в фронте и тем более vue я новичок, поэтому не судите строго=)

Comment: https://webdevkin.ru/posts/frontend/adminka-vue-5-components

Answer (score 0):

На первый взгляд у вас всё правильно. Для того, чтобы вы смогли увидеть ваше меню, нужно либо добавить текст в тег ссылки

```
<a href="/" ><input type="button" class="buttons " value="Main page"/>link_1</a>
```

либо правильно подключить файл со стилями

```
<style type="scss">
@import "./css/header.css";
</style>
```

либо прописать стили классу *buttons* непосредственно в файле Header.vue